# What does error?: (error: T) => void mean?

Tags: typescript

I've seen this syntax in some of the Typescript libraries, I'm trying to understand what it means.

`error?: (error: T) => void`

I've seen it used like this

```
class SomeClass {

    someFuction(error?: (error: T) => void){

    }

}
```

i get `error?`, optional error parameter, its the `:(error: T) =>void` part I'm not sure on. I know usually you would declare the parameter type directly after `:`

Thank you

S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct: `error?` means that it is optional

As for the rest:

```
: (error: T) => void
```

#### Breakdown

`:` - means that you're defining the type

`(error: T)` - means that it is a function

`error: T` - means that it takes a parameter `error` of type `T`

`=> void` - means that the return type of that function is void (no return value)

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the break down